# Rewrite SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables with structure as below.

```
create table  T1
( ColA        VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColB       VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColC       VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  startdt date,
  t1_price float(126) default 0 not null)


create table  T2
( ColA        VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColB       VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColC       VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  startdt date,
  t2_price float(126) default 0 not null)

create table T3
( ColA    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColB    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  ColC    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)         NOT NULL,
  startdt date,
  t3_price   float(126) default 0 not null)
```

Requirement is to populate T3_price in table T3 on condition that if there is an entry in T1 for same startdate, T1_price should be used else latest entry from T2 should be used. Below is sample data.

Entries in T1

```
ColA   ColB  ColC  Startdt    T1_Price  
VAL1   VAL2  VAL3  14/09/2014 100
VAL1   VAL2  VAL3  21/09/2014 100
VAL1   VAL2  VAL3  12/10/2014 200
```

Entries in T2

```
ColA   ColB  ColC  Startdt     T2_Price
VAL1   VAL2  VAL3  07/09/2014  200
VAL1   VAL2  VAL3  05/10/2014  300 


         07/09/14  14/09/14  21/09/14 28/09/14  05/10/14  12/10/14  19/10/14
T1_Price           100        100                         200
T2_Price 200       200                                    300 
T3_Price 
should   200       100        100      200      300       200       300
```

Can anyone please let me know if the above requirement can be achieved in a single update statement? I tried with the below statement.

```
UPDATE T3 r
   SET T3_price =
          (NVL (
              (SELECT T1_Price
                 FROM T1 d
                WHERE     r.colA = d.ColA
                      AND r.ColB = d.ColB
                      AND r.ColC = d.ColC
                      AND r.startdt = d.startdt),
              (SELECT T2_Price
                 FROM T2 b
                WHERE     r.colA = b.ColA
                      AND r.ColB = b.ColB
                      AND r.ColC = b.ColC
                      AND r.startdt >= b.startdt)))  --- I am sure that I am missing my logic here.
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT T1_Price
                 FROM T1 d
                WHERE     r.colA = d.ColA
                      AND r.ColB = d.ColB
                      AND r.ColC = d.ColC
                      AND r.startdt = d.startdt
           UNION
           SELECT T2_Price
                 FROM T2 b
                WHERE     r.colA = b.ColA
                      AND r.ColB = b.ColB
                      AND r.ColC = b.ColC
                      AND r.startdt >= b.startdt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T3
set t3.t3_price = T.price
FROM
(
 select T1.ColA, t1.ColB, t1.ColC, t1.t1_price as price , t1.startdt from T1
                          INNER JOIN T3
                          on t3.startdt = T1.startdt
 UNION
 select T2.ColA, t2.ColB, t2.ColC, t2.t2_price as price, t2.startdt from T2
                          INNER JOIN T3
                          on t3.startdt = T2.startdt
) T
where T.startdt = T3.startdt
and T.colA = T3.colA
and T.colB = T3.ColB
and T.colC = T3.colC
```

Comment: I wanted to update T3_Price joined on ColA, ColB,ColC and startdt. Looks like you misunderstood my question!!

Comment: The set statement itself is wrong!! I wanted to update T3_Price, but you are updating something else :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to achieve the logic. Please let me know if anyone can improvise it.

```
MERGE INTO  t3   dst
USING  (
       SELECT    t3.cola, t3.colb, t3.colc, t3.startdt
       ,         MAX (t1.t1_price)    AS t1_price
       ,         MAX (t2.t2_price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t2.startdt)
                                      AS last_t2_price
       FROM             t3
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  t1  ON   t1.cola     = t3.cola
                            AND  t1.colb     = t3.colb
                            AND  t1.colc     = t3.colc
                            AND  t1.startdt  = t3.startdt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  t2  ON   t2.cola     = t3.cola
                            AND  t2.colb     = t3.colb
                            AND  t2.colc     = t3.colc
                            AND  t2.startdt <= t3.startdt
       GROUP BY  t3.cola, t3.colb, t3.colc, t3.startdt
   )         src
ON     (    dst.cola     = src.cola
   AND  dst.colb     = src.colb
   AND  dst.colc     = src.colc
   AND  dst.startdt  = src.startdt
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET   dst.t3_price  = NVL (src.t1_price, src.last_t2_price);
```